# Hiding the .gitignore using VSCode's Files:Exclude

Tags: visual-studio-code, gitignore

I am trying to hide my .gitignore file in the VSCode project file explorer.

If I use this expression:

```
**/.*
```

Then .git, among a few others, will become hidden.

But when I try this:

```
**/.gitignore
```

I am still unable to hide it. I also tried a few other things, like these:

```
**/.git*
**/*.git*
**/*.gitignore
```

I feel a little silly, sorry! Thanks for your time, I sincerely appreciate it. It seems like a little silly thing, but I want to know!

Comment: I know this doesn't help in answering your question, but I'm wondering why you want to hide the file in the first place: I think it is a good idea to expose all files in the project in whatever IDE you are using, so that the whole project is editable from the IDE and discoverability is improved.

Comment: @julealgon As for me, I'd like to hide .gitignore because every time I want to commit some source code, I'm presented this extra file that I have to avoid.  I could just commit it, but if the repo ever goes public, Now people can see all the names of files that were in my project folder (like example code, status & planning notes, etc.).  But since I'm not really understanding this answer (where to enter the "**/.git", I'll probably just go ahead and commit it to keep it from nagging.

Answer (score 0):

The format in Visual Studio should be

```
**/.git
```

You could also make a global git ignore on your computer like this:

Make a hidden file in terminal called “.gitignore_global”

```
$ open ~/.gitignore_global
$ git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore_global
```

You can then edit this file by using vim or nano. Dealer's choice :)

```
vim ~/.gitignore_global
```

or

```
nano ~/.gitignore_global
```

and add your gitignore stuff like this:

```
.gitignore
*.gitignore
**/.gitignore*
```

The pros of making a global file is you will only need to do it once.  Here is some info I found on it: https://medium.com/self-modifying-code/create-a-global-gitignore-step-by-step-for-macos-and-windows-31a765291409

I hope this helps!

Comment: Where does "**/.git" get entered?  TIA.